# Creating a template for DataFlow throws the error AttributeError: 'RuntimeValueProvider' object has no attribute 'tableId'

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have made a pipeline with Apache Beam which runs successfully with the DataFlow runner. I'm trying to create a template, but when using a RuntimeValueProvider for the apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery transformer, the following error is thrown:

**AttributeError: 'RuntimeValueProvider' object has no attribute 'tableId'**.

The code (excerpt) looks as follows:

```
class ProcessOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_gcs',
            dest='output_gcs',
            default='gs://nlp-text-classification/results/stackoverflow_template',
            type=str,
            required=False,
            help='Google Cloud Storage Path.')

        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_bq_table',
            dest='output_bq_table',
            default='nlp-text-classification:stackoverflow.template_test',
            type=str,
            required=False,
            help='BigQuery table.')

process_options = options.view_as(ProcessOptions)

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    [...]
    "Write Posts to BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=process_options.output_bq_table,
                                                         schema=table_schema)
    [...]
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Dataflow uses a runner-native source that does not support templates by default. We do have a Beam source that supports templates. To use that, you have to enable an experiment using following flag.

```
--experiment=use_beam_bq_sink
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! If I use the flag stated above, everything works fine. However, I'm curious about the difference between the different sources of Dataflow (e.g. runner-native vs. Beam source). Do you have documentation for me that describes this aspect?

Comment: Native sink is fully implemented in Dataflow service. We recently added a Beam BigQuery sink which is expected to replace the native version but we have not fully migrated yet.

Comment: hello @chamikara, I am getting the below error message,, while creating template : AttributeError: 'RuntimeValueProvider' object has no attribute 'datasetId , beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(..)) I tried the --experiment flag but no luck. can u please assist

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'Write To BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(..)) I used beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(..) and also used --experiment=use_beam_bq_sink which worked for me and I am not getting the below error anymore AttributeError: 'RuntimeValueProvider' object has no attribute 'datasetId

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).